# Find the correspondences in tensors and make a replacement using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensor like this

```
[[1.0, 2.0]
[2.5, 3.0]]
```

and tensor like this

```
[1, 2]
```

ok, I know what is [1.0, 2.0] is corresponds to 1 and [2.5, 3.0] is corresponds to 2
How can I get tensor with value from second tensor if I have first tensor with deviations in some values?

For example: [[1.1, 2.00009]] -> [1]

Comment: This question is poorly worded.  Do you want to clip the numbers or convert them to integers?

Comment: I want convert vectors to integers.

Comment: The mapping is also unclear.  Your mapping two numbers into one digit. [2.5, 3.0] -> 2 what about [2.2, 3.0] -> ? and what about [2.5, 3.9] ->? do they both map to the digit "2"?  Are you trying to use the second tensor to index into the first tensor?